# When Can You Add -ing When Reducing a Relative Clause?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

With regards to reducing relative clauses to participle constructions, it seems that sometimes we are able to add -ing to verbs that normally cannot take the progressive tense.

*John, standing 4 foot 5, is hardly your man.*

*He built a room measuring 12 by 12 feet.*

Other times we can't:

*The girl liking John isn't to be trusted.*

What are the rules on this or where can I find them? If there are any.

Comment: Who says you can't say or write 'The girl liking John isn't to be trusted'?

Comment: Would have thought it sounded off to any native speaker's ears. I guess I could be wrong.

Comment: It's because of the semantic properties here of the verb "liking".

Comment: I think there may be more than one syntactic construction involved here. *John, standing 4ft 5, is hardly your man* doesn't make sense without the commas / pauses setting off the parenthetical element (because it's not a *restrictive* clause). But ***That man** standing 4ft 5 is hardly your man* is at least "credible", and ***The girl** watching him is stupid* is fine - except it only really works as a restrictive clause (*without* pauses / commas).

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce relative clauses:

- a room which measures 12 by 12 feet = a room measuring 12 by 12 feet
- the girl who likes John = the girl liking John

It doesn't work when who/that/which is an object:

- the books which I read != the books reading
  (Grammatically "the books reading" is fine but the meaning is different)

Maybe someone will correct me but I think it doesn't work when we use commas (non-defining relative clauses):

- We will raise £10,000 for local charities, which help the homeless. != ... local charities helping the homeless
  (Grammatically "local charities helping" is fine but the meaning is different

Comment: I think you're right about not being able to do it for non-defining relative clauses. I'm not quite in agreement that "The girl liking John isn't to be trusted" is acceptable.

Comment: According to ngram it is becoming more and more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=girl+liking%2Cgirl+who+likes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.

Comment: Why downvote? Is anything wrong here?

Comment: @Kjaamond Your Ngram search doesn't capture "liking" being used in reduced relative clauses: "...she has never seen a girl liking another girl...", "*That's fine if what's growing is good -- a girl liking a boy, a boy liking a girl*", "*Was she jealous? No. Just no. Not of this girl liking Brayden*". I didn't find a single one on the first page of hits. "*The girl liking John*" isn't correct.

Comment: @Kjaamond What your search probably does capture is that "like" is being used more frequently as a non-state verb in some structural contexts, such as: "*I'm liking this new look of yours*", but not (yet) in reduced relative clauses.